# Html.BeginForm - HTTP POST method - VB.NET 2012 MVC 4 Visual Studio

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

The focus is on the ***"controllerName As String"*** - part - of the **Html.BeginForm** function.

## The HTML:

#### root/Views/Home/Therequestform.vbhtml

```
    <h2>Therequestform</h2>

@Html.BeginForm("Therequest", "Home", method:= FormMethod.Post)

    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="ColorName" />
        <input type="submit" name="ColorName_SubmitButton" />
    </fieldset>
```

## The Controller:

#### root/Controllers/HomeController.vb

```
Function Therequestform() As ActionResult

    Return View()

End Function


    <HttpPost()>
    Function Therequest() As ActionResult

        Response.Write("The color you have submitted: " & Request.Form("ColorName"))

        Return View()
    End Function


End Class
```

## The Question:

**EDIT:** The call to the View is done above the request call to the HTTP POST method with the function "Therequest" - in the Controller.

The reference to the `ControllerName` has been done in the second part of the `Html.BeginForm`, whereas in the first part of `Html.BeginForm` the reference to the function to call a `request` to the `HTTP POST method` is done.

The problem I am having is, that after pressing the `submit button`, the call to the function (in the controller) is not done in the set location. Where the following error message comes up, after the ´submit button´ is pressed:

---

> **Server Error in Application.**
>   The view 'Therequest' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: The view
>   'Therequest' or its master was not found or no view engine supports
>   the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>
> ~/Views/Home/Therequest.aspx

~/Views/Home/Therequest.ascx

> ~/Views/Shared/Therequest.aspx

~/Views/Shared/Therequest.ascx

> ~/Views/Home/Therequest.cshtml

~/Views/Home/Therequest.vbhtml

> ~/Views/Shared/Therequest.cshtml

~/Views/Shared/Therequest.vbhtml

> **Source Error:** An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

---

The "search", or also the "call" is **not** done in the `set` location. Where by the parameter array of the *Html.BeginForm*, the to be `executed` function name is set, and also, the `controllerName` is set - which is set to (**root/Controllers/HomeController.vb**) - and in the third part the method is set to `POST`.

The question is, what is causing **it** to not do the call in the set location?

---

**The Tools Used:** VB.NET 2012, MVC 4, Visual Studio 2012, Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is trying to render View named `Therequest.vbhtml` whereas you have your view named `Therequestform.vbhtml`

Either change the view name to `Therequest.vbhtml` or change the controller name to `Therequestform` and all the places where it is referenced

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have gotten it to work.

I will have a closer look at how those connections are done.

Would this be the moment, where returnUrl could have been used? So, on page load, the print out happens, on the page holding the form?

Perhaps, this is also the "naming convention"?

Convention: a general agreement about basic principles or procedures; (Source: The Meriam-Webster Dictionary)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the question

Comment: I could tell, that it is `just` the `function` named as such, and the `Return` returning the `View` by the `function's name`. I will continue thinking this through, with a focus on the connections - where I think that the `View` can be also called in different ways. To which the last question was also directed at, which I am stating to comment on that question.

Comment: It appears you are lacking some basic understanding of how MVC Framework works. I suggest you looking at something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43153/Beginners-Guide-s-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-Part-1)

Comment: The model in this example is skipped. Having two functions, one separate to call up the View has not worked, since the functions would have the same name "Therequest". Calling the View differently has been content of the latter question. The View after the request to the HTTP POST method, does happen, after the `submit button` is pressed, yet I can not define it as concise here, in the comment section, so I will leave at that.